# Counting how many times an individual has performed a task in the last year

Tags: excel, duplicates, counting

My spreadsheet’s colums are:

Date | Name

I have a list of names, one for each day of the year, which are inserted by users.
If an individual is listed on a given day, they have to perform a certain task.

I want to be able to count how many times they have been allocated a task in the last 365 days.
As it stands, the Excel Workbook has individual sheets for each year.

I’ve hit a bit of a brick wall as to how I will be able to count these names but only count them if they are within 365 days of today.
Using COUNTIF is great, but I then have duplicates which are not automatically filtered out.

Comment: Add some code. What have you done so far?

Comment: I think you need to show some data and give an example of what constitutes a duplicate.